# What does "I had every last one of them" mean?

Tags: idioms, slang, colloquialisms

I heard this quote from a Channel 4 sitcom the IT crowd

> I'm gonna go, I may not come back but I want to say this. That
>   accounts team, I had every last one of them.

It is said by Douglas Reynholm, the boss. But what does "I had every last one of them" mean in this quotation? What does he intend it to mean?

Comment: More context needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahem. Stand by for **adult content**.

To "have" someone is slang for having sex with them (there's also a subtle connotation of conquest and arrogance implied as well - like bragging). By saying he's "had every last one of them", the boss is claiming to have had sex with all members of the Accounts team.

Comment: While what you say may be the case it cannot be said for certain from the given information. It can be used in other situations as well.  For example I could set up a practical joke and then say, "I had you all."  Or I could be a politician who thought he had confirmed that everyone on the Accounting Team was going to vote for him.  Then when the election results come in, he's surprised he didn't win and exclaims, "I had every last one of them last night?!"

Comment: @Jim true from the information in the question alone if you don't know the show it references, but this answer is clearly correct if you do; the character mentioned is egotistical and sex-obsessed, and often talking about sexual conquests or sexual ambitions.
That and I've seen the episode in question, and it's quite clear that's what he meant.

Comment: @JonHanna- Thanks. Good to know.  (As you rightly guessed, I don't watch the show.)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call the sense slang after so long in use.  It may have been more a slang sense when Shakespeare wrote "Was ever woman in this humor wonne: Ile haue her, but I will not keepe her long." and "Why? shee's neither fish nor flesh, a man knowes not where to haue her." Even then I'd say it was more figurative than slangy, though the idea of sex as act of possession being so long-standing that one could even consider it literal within the context of that concept.